# MSVS2015: как в server explorer открыть database diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Читаю книгу Троелсена "Язык программирования C# 5.0 и платформа .NET 4.5"
На странице 763 написано следующее:

> И, наконец, между таблицами Customers, Orders и Inventory нужно
>   установить отношения “родительский-дочерний”. В Visual Studio это
>   делается очень просто, т.к. на этапе проектирования можно вставить
>   новую диаграмму базы данных. Для этого откройте Server Explorer,
>   щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на узле Database Diagrams базы AutoLot и выберите пункт контекстного меню Add New Diagram.

Проблема в том, что у меня нет такого пункта меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как же добавить диаграмму?

Comment: можно как вариант использовать [SSMS Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50003)

Comment: Это да, но интересует как это можно сделать через студию. Почему у меня нет этого пункта меню? Может у меня что-то с настройками не так?